# Android: adb does not recognize "Galaxy Note5"

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

I recently purchased Samsung Galaxy Note 5, and tried to keep developing my android project. My previous phone (S5) was working perfectly, but I guess I am not lucky with this phone.

I am getting this error (which is common error)

```
List of devices attached
DeviceName            unauthorized
```

I have tried the following so far

```
1) Revoking USB debugging authorization
2) kill and start server with restarting computer
3) update sdk to the latest version (SDK Platforms and SDK Tools)
```

Is Galaxy Note 5 not allowed to use for developing yet? or am I missing some step? I have worked on android development for 2 years, and this is very weird...

Comment: When you've attache device to computer for the first time, is there any installation process?

Comment: @Chitrang Yes, which is very weird. It did not give me any popup like RSA registration

Comment: Install either drivers or kies to make it work. http://www.technobuzz.net/samsung-galaxy-s6-edge-note-5-usb-drivers/

Comment: You enabled USB debugging option in the Developers menu right...?

Comment: My note 5 has never worked since the day I got it. I Have tried everything. It doesn't even show up as a file storage device. I think the USB port is actually faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. enable the developer option
2. enable the usb debug mode inside developer option
3. (Important!)
   Make sure to use USB drivers from Samsung. 
   I have many experiences the Generic usb driver from google don't work for Samsung abd debug (although it can catch mobile when plug the usb). After install Samsung driver the RSA confirm pop will appear.

NOTE: Don't need to install KIES full suite just search 'Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones'(in may case Samsung-Usb-Driver-v1.5.59.0.exe) for it is a pure driver.